# Trying to cross compile Python I'm getting an unrecognised emulation mode

Tags: python, android-ndk, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I've been working on a GitHub project that cross compiles Python for Android
https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/tree/clang

Google is deprecating gcc in the NDK soon, so I have been trying to switch from using gcc, to clang.

I stumbled across this project a couple of years back and have been trying to maintain it with current versions of the libraries, but this one has me stumped.  I have updated the branch above, and I think it's compiling with clang, but it's failing to link with the following error

```
/home/python3-android/sdk/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: elf_x86_64

Supported emulations: aarch64linux aarch64elf aarch64elf32 aarch64elf32b aarch64elfb armelf armelfb aarch64linuxb aarch64linux32 aarch64linux32b armelfb_linux_eabi armelf_linux_eabi

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

../Makefile.shared:164: recipe for target 'link_app.' failed
```

At the end of the first line it's saying unrecognised **emulation mode elf_x86_64**.  I don't understand where it's getting that emulation mode, or how to change it.

I get the same error for arm or arm64. I use 2 files to setup the environment and the makefile variables

Env -- https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/blob/clang/env

and

build_single.sh -- https://github.com/GRRedWings/python3-android/blob/clang/mk/build_single.sh

I am relatively new to cross-compile and what is needed, and at this point just don't know where else to look.

Based on the script I inherited, I have both CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS starting with

-target aarch64-none-linux-android -gcc-toolchain ${NDK_ROOT}/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing `-target aarch64-linux-android`, so Clang is defaulting to targeting x86_64, but using the aarch64 linker that you provided.

The NDK ships a tool to do this work for you: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html

Comment: Thanks for the post, I'll be sure to check out the tool.  I think I'm past this problem in the latest clang commit, but now Python fails to compile.  Maybe the tool can help

Comment: Did you happen to look at the build.sh for Python?  I'm not having much luck using the NDK tool you mentioned.  I'm quite new to cross compile & builds on linux. Is this supposed to generate a script for me?

Comment: Read the section at the bottom of the doc: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html#building_open_source_projects_using_standalone_toolchains

Comment: From experience, the way python source is used with setup.py I was under the impression you had to build the intermediate hostpython before you could build for the target, iirc python3 source just wouldn't compile in a one step host, target mix